# Find the supreme and infimum of the following set, $\left \{\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}: n\in \Bbb N\right \}$.

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Find the supreme and infimum of the set $$A=\left \{\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}: n\in \Bbb N\right \}$$

We claim that, $\inf A=\sqrt{3}$, y $\sup A=\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}.$ Let's prove it.

**Supremo:** Let's first show that $\sup A=\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}.$. Indeed, we must show the following two conditions,

$a)$ $\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is upper bound for $A$.

$b)$ For all $\epsilon>0$, exists $a\in A$ such that $$\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}-\epsilon<a. $$

To show $ a) $, let's notice the following,
$$\begin{align*}
    0&\leq 2\\
    4n^2&\leq 2+4n^2\\
    4n^2&\leq 2(1+2n^2)\\
    2n&\leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2n^2}\\
    6n&\leq 3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2n^2}\\
    \dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}&\leq \dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}.
\end{align*}$$
In this way, we have shown that $ a) $ is true.

Let's show $ b) $. Since $ n \in \mathbb N $, then clearly we have that $ 9n ^ 2> 1 + 2n ^ 2 $, from which it follows that $ 3n> \sqrt {1 + 2n ^ 2} $. Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{2\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}&>3\\ 
    \dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}&>3\\
    \dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}&>-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}+3.
\end{align*}$$

Now, for Archimedean property given $ \epsilon> 0 $ (in this case $ \sqrt {2} \epsilon> 0 $), there exists $ n \in \Bbb N $ such that $$\sqrt{2}\epsilon>\dfrac{1}{n}>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}>\dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}>-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}+3.$$
Then,
$$\begin{align*}
    -\dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}+3&<\sqrt{2}\epsilon\\
    -\dfrac{\sqrt{2}3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}&<\sqrt{2}\epsilon-3\\
    -\sqrt{2}3n&<\sqrt{2}\epsilon \sqrt{1+2n^2}-3\sqrt{1+2n^2}\\
    3\sqrt{1+2n^2}-\sqrt{2}3n&<\sqrt{2}\epsilon\sqrt{1+2n^2}\\
    \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}&<\epsilon\\
    \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}-\epsilon&<\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}
\end{align*}$$
Which shows that $ \sup A = \dfrac {3 \sqrt {2}} {2} = \dfrac {3} {\sqrt {2}} $.

Is my proof correct? Any suggestions to make it simpler? And some suggestion also for the $ \epsilon $ but with the lowest.

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier and less work to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$ ? Because $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup A$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf A$ and they share the same common value in this case

Comment: You do very complicated. $n\mapsto \frac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}$ is increasing...

Comment: We are not working with that definition yet. We are just starting the course, and to show that it is supreme we were given only the property of approximation to the supreme.

Comment: then you just need to mimic the proof showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{\sqrt{1+2n^2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$. It will be much easier and give you a more accurate result

Comment: I know what you mean by trying that. But in this course that is called "Fundamentals of Mathematics II" we still have no notion that it is a limit. @CSquared

Comment: Your proof is correct!